# Can you throw an exception from inside an anonymous implementation of Runnable

Tags: java, runnable

I am creating a simple game, and I want it to stop when a `DeathException` is thrown. Here is my runGame method:

```
public void runGame() {
    while(true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                board.nextFrame();
                repaint();
                setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The method `board.nextFrame()` throws `DeathException`. I'm not sure how to break the while loop from inside the anonymous implementation of the `Runnable`.

Comment: You can throw an exception, but it will not happen in the while loop. It will happen on the event queue.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) for `EventQueue#invokeLater()`?  Do you understand what that does?

Comment: You want to end the entire program?

Comment: Regarding the actual question in the title: yes, if it is unchecked - no, if it is checked - anonymous or not does not matter.

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting you.. In any case, create an atomic boolean as the while-loop's condition.. `try-catch` the `nextFrame` and if an exception is thrown, set the atomic boolean to false in order to break out. BUT you also probably don't want to be invoking later in an infinite loop like that..

Comment: The infinite loop is a placeholder. I wasn't sure what condition to put.

Comment: Thanks @Brandon, the atomic boolean idea worked.

Comment: No, an atomic boolean will not solve your problem.  Yes, in *most* cases, it might happen to stop the loop within the 50ms delay you've given it. What if your runnable takes longer than 50ms though? You end up going another cycle AFTER the cycle in which the exception will be thrown. You first need to understand the concept of threads, then read [`EventQueue#invokeAndWait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeAndWait(java.lang.Runnable)). When you understand the difference, you will see the solution.